# Prove that $f(x) = x^3 -x $ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

**Problem:**  Prove that the mapping $ f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R , f(x) = x^3-x$ is surjective.

Let $y\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=y$ for some $x\in  \mathbb R$. Then $x^3-x=y$. If we can express $x$ in terms of $y$, then we can say something about surjectiveness. But I stuck at that point.

What is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=\infty$ and the function is continuous hence it is surjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any odd-degree polynomial with real coefficients has at least one real root (in fact, it has an odd number of them, counted with multiplicity). Now, consider the polynomial $x^3-x-a$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. A root of this polynomial then gives a real number $b$ for which $b^3-b=a$. Hence, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R} \ \exists b \in \mathbb{R} \ (b^3-b=a)$, so the function $f(x)=x^3-x$ is surjective.

More generally, any odd-degree polynomial with real coefficients is surjective (from the reals to the reals).

Answer (score 5):

You have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)=-\infty$, thus $f$ is surjective by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).